# PLSQL Add specific column according to input

Tags: plsql

my table looks like

```
startday            endday            day1       day2      day3       day4
1                        4               2          3         5          3      
3                        4               3          5         1          6    
2                        3               3          7         10         9
```

input for the function should be startday and endday.

if input is 1 and 3, output should be day1+day2+day3

if input is 2 and 3, output should be day2+day3

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So when input is  s 1 and 3 output should be (2+3+5+3+7+10).. Can you comfirm what will happen when rows changes like in case of 1 as start day and 3 as end date

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION (P_INPUT_01   IN NUMBER,
                                        P_INPUT_02   IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   V_RESULT   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT (CASE
              WHEN P_INPUT_01 = 1 AND P_INPUT_02 = 3 THEN DAY1 + DAY2 + DAY3
              WHEN P_INPUT_01 = 2 AND P_INPUT_02 = 3 THEN DAY2 + DAY3
              ELSE NULL -- WARNING: NULL IN ANY OTHER CASE!!
           END)
     INTO V_RESULT
     FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE STARTDAY = P_INPUT_01 AND ENDDAY = P_INPUT_02;

   RETURN V_RESULT;
END MY_FUNCTION;
```

Usage example:

```
SELECT my_function (2, 3) FROM DUAL;
```

Result: 17

========================

To prepare the environment I've used these statements:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
   startday   NUMBER,
   endday     NUMBER,
   day1       NUMBER,
   day2       NUMBER,
   day3       NUMBER,
   day4       NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
    VALUES (1,
            4,
            2,
            3,
            5,
            3);

INSERT INTO my_table
    VALUES (3,
            4,
            3,
            5,
            1,
            6);

INSERT INTO my_table
    VALUES (2,
            3,
            3,
            7,
            10,
            9);

COMMIT;
```